# Installing packages using Pypy

Tags: python, windows, pypy

I'm trying to install a python source package that has `C` files using pypy:

```
pypy setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But it's returning:

```
fatal error C1033: cannot open program database 'c:\users\g1745 iron\downloads\kinterbasdb-3.3.0\"c:\users\user\downloads\kinterbasdb-3.3.0\build\lib.win32-2.7\kinterbasdb\_kinterbasdb.pdb"'
error: command 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Do i need do any extra configuration? With python:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The installation will work.

Thank.s

Comment: I think if `pypy` supported native C extensions written for CPython, they would have `numpy` by now...

Answer (score 0):

For Example:##installing a pyuv

```
pip install pyuv
```

Building

Get the source:

```
git clone https://github.com/saghul/pyuv
```

Linux:

```
./build_inplace
```

Mac OSX:

```
(XCode needs to be installed)
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
./build_inplace
```

Microsoft Windows (with Visual Studio):

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

for further details:check this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyuv/1.3.0)

Installing PyPy:

```
$ tar xf pypy-2.1.tar.bz2
$ ./pypy-2.1/bin/pypy
```

to see this [link](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html) its helps you